# How do you scripted the effect of pressing [Ctrl + Home] (Control key and the Home key)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I want to add to many of the scripts I have already written, the ability to focus on the first cell, in the upper-most row, of a filtered (or not filtered) table in Google Sheets.

I know this sounds minor and I should be able to tell those involved to just press (Ctrl + Home), but honestly, I think it would be easier "IF" I could just do this in my scripts, if possible.

Thanks a head of time to those who help!!!!!

I tried macro --> record, but all I got was the cell that was activated. Not the steps used to come to the conclusion of which cell is the correct cell.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
function goToBottom() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let lr = sh.getLastRow();
  let mr = sh.getMaxRows();
  if (lr == mr) {
    sh.insertRowAfter(mr);
  }
  sh.getRange(lr + 1, 1).activate();
}

function goToTop() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(2, 1).activate();
}
```

Comment: Sorry Cooper, This did not work. It just brings me back to the top row. I want it to scroll my sheet to the upper most UN-hidden row of a filtered (or un-filtered) table. But thanks for trying!!!

Comment: Maybe I should mention that I have rows 1 thru 7 frozen a the top so they can be seen at all times when scrolling through the tables' data.